# Laravel create and retrieve data for simple relation ship

Tags: php, laravel

in laravel i want to create simple relation ship to retrieve data between them, but i cant and i get error

i have two table as `amount_repositories` and `report_transactions`, `report_transactions` table has many fields in `amount_repositories` table, and `amount_repositories` belongs to `report_transactions`,

`amount_repositories` is separated data from `report_transactions` table, then `amount_repositories` belongs to `report_transactions`.

`ReportMerchantTransactions` class:

```
class ReportMerchantTransactions extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'report_transactions';
    public function amount_repositories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AmountRepositories');
    }
}
```

`AmountRepositories` class:

```
class AmountRepositories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'amount_repositories';
    public function report_merchant_transactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ReportMerchantTransactions');
    }
}
```

`AmountRepositories` migration file:

```
class AmountRepositories extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('amount_repositories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('amount');
            $table->integer('report_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('report_id')->references('id')->on('report_transactions');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('amount_repositories');
    }
}
```

now i want to get all data in `AmountRepositories` that belongs to `ReportMerchantTransactions`:

```
$posts= ReportMerchantTransactions::find(1)->amount_repositories;
```

unfortunately i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown     column'
amount_repositories.report_merchant_transactions_id' 
in 'where     clause' 
(SQL: select * from `amount_repositories` where 
    `amount_repositories`.`report_merchant_transactions_id` = 1 and 
`amount_repositories`.`report_merchant_transactions_id` is not null)
```

Comment: Your error says everything.

Comment: @akasummer yes, i know that, i can't fix this problem and i dont know what's my code problem

Comment: @akasummer , then whats my code problem??? do you know that?

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on. You textual description in the beginning confuses me. Your error says that `amount_repositories` table doesn't have `report_merchant_transactions_id` column. What's the schema of this table?

Comment: @akasummer i pasted the table schema when i create post, thats created by Migration file,please review again my post

Comment: @akasummer i want to get all `amount_repositories` in `ReportMerchantTransactions` table

Comment: What columns are in your amount_repositories table?

Comment: You need to pass other arguments in your model definition of `hasMany()`. By default, Laravel will assume the FK is `table_name_id` but in your case it seems the FK is `report_id`. It is defined like this `hasMany('table_name', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you need to pass additional parameters into the `belongsTo()` or `hasMany()` methods.

By default, Laravel will assume that the foreign key linking the tables is the current table's name with `_id` concatenated to it. The error points you in that direction as well; notice that it says it cannot locate a column named `amount_repositories.report_merchant_transactions_id` which is the default foreign key generated by Laravel. Since it seems your foreign key does not follow that convention, which is totally fine, Laravel offers additional parameters to be passed to it to help this.

The concept is: `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` pulled [from docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Not positive of your model layout, but something along these lines should get you going.

```
class AmountRepositories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'amount_repositories';

    /**
     * Pass the FK along with method
     */
    public function report_merchant_transactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ReportMerchantTransactions', 'report_id');
    }
}
```

This says that the `AmountRepositories` table has a relationship with `ReportMerchantTransactions` using foreign key of `report_id`.

Hope this helps. You're close, just need to add a little more data to your relationship data and you're there!